# Bokeh plot JS path in sphinx html hosted on gh-pages

Tags: html, python-sphinx, bokeh, github-pages

I am attempting to host some sphinx based documentation on gh-pages using the bokeh-plot extension using the 'bokeh-plot' directive in the RST files. I am able to serve the generated html and associated JS to get the interactive plots working fine with a local host flask server.

My issue is when hosting on gh-pages the scripts generated for the plots get put in a top level 'scripts' folder (build/html/scripts) and the generated html src is then set as '/scripts'. The issue appears to lie in this path not being a relative path and then resolves to the top level gh-pages url/scripts instead of being the full repository url/scripts. When I manually edit the html to be the proper relative path the plots work fine on gh-pages. What is the best way to resolve this to include the interactive bokeh plots in my documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Making the plot scripts accessible via relative paths is [still an open issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/5955) Unfortunately it's also a chunk of work, and there are lots of issues and few core devs, so I doubt it will get prioritized soon.

Do you know an absolute path that *will* work on the deployed GH pages site? If so (it seems there must be?) then my best suggestion is just to edit your local install of bokeh to point to that location, instead of the hard-coded `"/scripts"` value before you generate the output:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/bokeh/sphinxext/bokeh_plot.py#L142

A slightly better solution would be to submit a PR to either make this path configurable, or to make relative paths work. If you might be interested in working on these things please reach out on the project GitHub

Comment: Thank you. I have a a bit of a hacky solution to make it work for my specific use case. Unfortunately I don't have a ton of time to find an elegant method worthy of a PR. What I ended up doing was:  place a known string ($REL_PATH$) at the front of the path when the script was parsed in `_process_script`, finding the document depth in `run` by counting the '/' chars in env.docname, then replace the tagged string with the appropriate number of '../'. I am building the docs on linux right now but it has been working on gh-pages with these changes. I can post details on gist if needed.